# set the color of menu same as its hover background once the page opens

Tags: jquery, css, menu, hover

I have a horizontal menu on a page like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/classified/siteassets/css/mymenu.css" />
<div id="content-container">
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://mysite/Classified/Pages/Training.aspx">Training</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mysite/Classified/Pages/Briefing.aspx">Briefing</a></li>     
    <li><a href="http://mysite/Classified/Pages/Resources.aspx">Resources</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The menu is styled like this:

```
#content-container {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, serif;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}    
#content-container ul {
    border-bottom: 18px solid #C93;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0 -10px;;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    overflow: visible;
    width:98%;
}    
#content-container ul li {
    float: left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 14.25%;
}    
#content-container ul li a {
    border-left: 1px #fff solid;
    line-height:36px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ddd;
    background-color:#2E4B68;
    display:block;
    font-size:1.5em;

}
#content-container ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #C93;
    color:#000;
}
```

What I need to do is when one of the link is clicked the respective page opens, i need to have the same color on the menu tab that opened as its hover color. I need to do that by finding which page opened by checking the url using javascript and setting the background color of that li item dynamically using jquery to the same as its hover color so users know that's what is currently opened page. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#content-container ul li a").each(function(i, item) {
        if($(item).attr("href") == window.location) {
            $(item).css("background-color, #c93");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $("#content-container").on({"mouseover":function(){
// when you mouseover a 'ul li a' this event fires. store it's current background color
   $(this).data("background-color",$(this).css("background-color"));
  },"click":function(event){
// someone clicked it, grab the color and set the parent li background-color
   $(this).parent().css({background-color:$(this).data("background-color")});
  }},"ul li a", null);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#content-container a").each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).attr("href")==location.href)
              jQuery(this).css({"background-color": "#C93",color:"#000"});
    });
});
```

It will go over your menu, see if a link is matching the current page address and style that.

You should really use css classes though for this.

*P.s.: untested code.*

Answer (score 0):

Change the background color (set the desired color in a class) of the tab dynamically with onclick event.

hope fully, this link may help you.

http://api.jquery.com/css/